# Swift 3 pass data through completion with userID

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to run a check on Firebase to see if a user exists, then I need to check for specific vales before continuing. I currently have this:

```
func myFirebaseNetworkDataRequest(finished: () -> Void) {
    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
                self.userUUID = (user.uid)
                getUser(userUUID: self.userUUID)
                finished()
    }
}
```

In my view did load:

```
myFirebaseNetworkDataRequest {

        // perform further operations here after data is fetched
        if AppState.sharedInstance.user == true  {
                    //present 1st view controller 
        } else {
                    //present 2nd view controller
        }
```

In my "getUser" function:

```
func getUser(userUUID: String) {
    let userFacebookRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(userUUID)
    //The rest of the Firebase function. 

    AppState.sharedInstance.user == results.active
    //active is = to true
```

What currently happens is that if presents the 2nd view controller because firebase hasent finished yet. I realize I need a block because firebase is already asnyc but how do I send userUUID through the closure/block?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your closure parameter have an parameter of it's own. Something like,

```
func myFirebaseNetworkDataRequest(finished: (_ isAuthenticated: Bool) -> Void)
```

Then in your viewDidLoad, you would make your request...

```
open override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.myFirebaseNetworkDataRequest( (isAuthenticated) -> {
        if isAuthenticated {
            // Present VC1
        } else {
            // Present VC 2
        }
    }
}
```